# format DateTime with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working with Dates in javascript I'm using this way to get my date object

```
let date = new Date(1615878420000) //passing time in milliseconds by parameter
```

I need the time of date in 24 hours format. I can understand why when I use this way the console browser return me this:

[image]

And when I make this:

```
let date = Date (1615878420000)
```

If I don't put the word new it return me a string but this string has the time in 24 hours format

[image]

If I make this:

```
let date = new Date(1615878420000)
date.getHours()
```

[image]

I get a number 1 supposing that the time is 13:00  I would like to get 13 when i use getHours()

Comment: If all you want to do is get the hours in 24 hour format, you can use [date.getUTCHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours).

Comment: `Date` called without `new` ignores all arguments, and just returns the current date/time as string. Passing some number doesn't change anything.

Comment: `date.toLocaleString()` might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get hours doesn't work how you think it does. If you read the spec on it, it will give you a number from 0 - 23 representing the hour for the specified date, according to **local time**. So you are likely seeing a conversion because of that.

[gethours spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours)

For the first example below, I will see 9 in example one because I am -0400. For the second I will see 13 because it's what the hour is for UTC.

```js
const time = new Date(1615899608000);
const hoursLocal = time.getHours();
const hoursUTC = time.getUTCHours();


console.log(hoursLocal);// will hour for whatever your time zone is
console.log(hoursUTC);// will be hour for UTC
```